# MD5 в число увеличится ли вероятность коллизии

Tags: php, хеширование, md5

Появилась задача преобразовать md5 hash в целое число. Так как диапазон букв a-f, на ум пришло следующее:

```
function numeric_hash($string) {
    $converter = array(
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 1,
        'c' => 2,
        'd' => 3,
        'e' => 4,
        'f' => 5
    );

    return strtr(md5($string), $converter);
}

echo numeric_hash('hello_world');
```

Вопрос: Возрастет ли от этого вероятность коллизий, по моей логике не должно, так как какая разница будет там b или 1, (по крайней мере я так думаю).

Данный хеш не будет использоваться в криптографических целях, а всего лишь как уникальный id.

Comment: Хм, интересный вариант, тоже интересует данный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md5` - это 128 бит данных. Запись символами 0-9a-f - то есть в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления - лишь распространённая традиция. Вы можете без влияния на криптографическую стойкость использовать любую форму вывода, обеспечивающую однозначное преобразование. Можете использовать любой алфавит, хоть 128-символьную строку из букв А и Б для отображения состояния соответствующего бита - вы сохраните все 128 бит данных.

Однако если ваше преобразование выполняется с потерей данных, как например замена литеры a в шестнадцатеричном представлении на 0 - так же используемому в этом представлении - то вы теряете данные. Соответственно уменьшаете количество возможных вариантов и потому, конечно, увеличиваете число коллизий.

> Появилась задача преобразовать md5 hash в целое число.

Это обычное преобразование систем счисления. Из шестнадцатеричной (или сразу двоичной при желании) в десятеричную. Для штатных функций PHP вроде [`base_convert`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) или `hexdec`, впрочем, 128-битное число великовато. И вам нужно сделать (или взять готовую) пользовательскую реализацию. В комментариях к мануалу PHP по функции base_convert приведено несколько вариантов.

Comment: Да число великовато, но я видел реализации с base_convert, и substr, но от этого мне кажется реально возрастут коллизии, я так до конца и не понял, могу ли я использовать мой вариант или нет?

Comment: У вас есть числа `123b` и `1231`. Это разные числа, верно? Затем вы применяете своё преобразование. Что получили? Коллизию и получили. Почему? Потому что заменили символ имеющий собственно значение на символ так же использующийся в этом словаре, но имеющий другое значение. После корректного перевода системы счисления вы получите то же самое число, но записанное иначе. Из-за уменьшения мощности алфавита вы будете вынуждены использовать больше символов - но после обратного преобразования вы получите те же самые данные который у вас и были.

Comment: @Мелкий, Простите мне просто тоже интересно, если автор просто хочет хранить значения в том же виде без преобразований разве что то изменится? Было: 123ef, стало 12345. Если не будет повторятся md5 по логике получившееся число после преобразования его функцией тоже не должно повторится...

Comment: @JohnDoe До преобразования было два неповторяющихся хеша `12345` и `123ef`. После преобразования получили такие хеши `12345` и `12345`. Я ответил на ваш вопрос? А вот если сделать замену `0` => `00`, `a` => `01`, `b` => `02`, ... ``f` => `06`, тогда преобразование будет взаимнооднозначным и новых коллизий не возникнет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, А разве md5 может состоять только из цифр?

Comment: @VadimPedchenko, он только из шестнадцатиричных цифр и состоит

Comment: @КириллМалышев, Так, а если мы считаем её как десятичную, вернее как строку с буквами и цифрами, то как в таком случае может быть совпадение? Где было a34 будет 134, при условии что a34 не повторится, то и 134 не повторится, при условии что буква обязательна

Comment: @VadimPedchenko, `разве md5 может состоять только из цифр?` - я повторюсь: md5 - это 128 бит информации. Отображать в виде 32-символьной строки HEX - не более чем привычка. Вы можете закодировать 128 бит используя любой произвольный алфавит.